# How to automatically round the square ends of every glyph in a Sans Font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector

How to take the square ends and corners of a font like the Google Noto Sans CJK font:

[image]

And make it *rounded* like this font:

[image]

There must be some effect or something in some program that you just apply to every character that can do this. Is that so? How can you accomplish this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Rounded fonts are *designed* as rounded by the font creator.

Comment: The easiest way would be to find one which has actually been designed as a rounded font. Something [like this one](https://chinesefontdesign.com/good-night-retro-chinese-font-simplified-chinese.html) perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Round cornered fonts are designed like that.

That said, you can convert the text into curves and adjust the corners of the characters, but the text is no longer editable. Unless you convert that back into a font file.

You can also just apply **Effect** > **Stylize** > **Round Corners** but then all the corners will be rounded (if you check your examples you'll see that only the ends are rounded, the internal corners in the **R** /  **D** / **E** / **L** are still sharp).

Answer (score 1):

Getting a good effect is non-trivial, I'm afraid. You can read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170330135712/https://www.fontfont.com/staticcontent/downloads/FF_DIN_Round_Digital_Block_Letters.pdf?1308319796), (page 16) but basically, if you put round ends on the end of the letters they look bigger (as you've added something), if you replace stroke endings with round ends the letters look smaller (you've removed something). Both those effects noticeably change the way the letters look. You also need to make the letters taper as the curve starts, if you just put a semicircle you see an awkward bump when the semicircle starts.